# Laravel 5.2 white page on error

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting white screen if any error in code, I can not see error.

Below are things I have checked:

- `debug` is set to `true` in env and config file
- `storage` folder has `777` permissions
- `bootstrap` folder has `777` permissions
- PHP version is 5.6

What am I missing why I get blank/white screen on error?

What should I do to see error?

Comment: Look at the logs. Either the server (apache/nginx) logs, or in `storage/logs`. That will give you the reason why you're getting a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your `php.ini` error reporting settings might be set not to report errors. If that is the case, you can see the errors by doing this in your code, before where you think it is crashing like.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This should show you the errors you need to see.